# File path given correct but file showing error file not found

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I am creating small application which is for save data using on javafx... the problem is showing me that when I  run my application is the file not found .. 
error message

```
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\sample-app.conf (The system cannot find the path specified)`
```

code for error lines are as follows

```
    private String configFile = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "sample-app.conf";

public  boolean loadLicense() {
      //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
     try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(configFile));

            licenseString = properties.getProperty("license-string");
            activatedLicenseString = properties.getProperty("activated-license-string");
            if (properties.getProperty("license-type") != null) {
                licenseType = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("license-type"));
            }
            if (properties.getProperty("activated-license-type") != null) {
                activatedLicenseType = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("activated-license-type"));
            }

            hostname = properties.getProperty("floating-license-server-hostname");
            if (properties.getProperty("floating-license-server-port") != null) {
                int portnumber = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("floating-license-server-port"));
            }

            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Lenovo")` isn't doing what you want. It is unclear what you want this to return, but it is returning null.

Comment: @jdv   i am creating a small application based data saving in config  file...but the I give the path also there but showing the error message that  "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: C:\users\leveno is the path to reach the file

Comment: You are not using this path. You are using a String as a parameter to `System.getProperty()` which is returning null. Turn this around. What do you expect `System.getProperty("C:\blah\blah")` to return? Please read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Perhaps you want "user.dir" but this is not clear. What do you want to do? Because the existing code is not doing it.

Comment: @jdv problem is very simple.i have config file ... need to check that data is there or not .. but config file is uploading .. given current path

Comment: The path you are building to get to the file is **wrong** and it will **never** be right if you use `System.getProperty()` _the way you are using it_. This is not what `.getProperty()` is for. However, it is not possible to tell you how to fix it, other than "construct a path that doesn't have null in it, possibly by not using `System.getProperty()` at all, or possibly by using it in a different way."

Comment: What do you expect `System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Lenovo")` to return? The answer to this question is key. Because it will generally always return a Java null. Then think about what the configFile String will then hold when it gets to your `loadLicense()` method.

Comment: @jdv so what I required there ?

Comment: in load license need to verify the data

Comment: @jdv what is different way ?

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong thing. You need to think about how you want to construct a path to the .conf file before you do anything. Only you can tell us where this file might reside. Again: why are you using System.getProperty()? What are you expecting this to return?

Comment: the config file is in "C:\Users\Lenovo"

Comment: system.getproperty() is using for check the file config file is there or not

Comment: That is not what `System.getProperty()` does. It retrieves the value of the system property passed to it, if found, of the running JVM. Did you read the docs link I provided?

Comment: yes.. I update my code but still getting another error calling "null pointer exception"

Comment: Where is the NPE coming from? What line? Have you thought about WHY you are getting an NPE?

Comment: @jdv null pointer coming in "properties.load(new FileInputStream(configFile));"

Comment: You should provide the stack trace. Also, have you tried debugging through the code? What is `configFile` just before you call `properties.load()`

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are constructing a path using `System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Lenovo")` but this is almost certainly returning null. This is likely the root of your problem, though since you do not provide a stacktrace, it is not possible to be sure.

This is because `System.getProperty()` is [intended to return a value for a property key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) that you pass in, and "C:\Users\Lenovo" is not a property key (unless you are running the JVM with a `-D` option setting it as a property).

So, the solution depends on what you want to do.

1. Maybe this .conf file is *always* in that same location. If this is the case, then set `configFile` to the fixed String version of your pathname.
2. Maybe you want to pass in `-D "my.license.conf.rootdir=C:\\Users\\Lenovo"` to the JVM, in which case you would use `System.getProperty("my.license.conf.rootdir")` instead and construct your path that way.
3. Something else. You construct a path some other way that makes sense for you.

Whatever you do, once you have a String pathname you can validate it using typical API like `File.exists()` before passing it onto code that actually expects the pathname to a specific file to be present on the system, and correct in your code.

That is, you want to, in order:

- Derive, assemble, or define a pathname, probably as some sort of String
- Validate this pathname so you know there is a concrete, on-disk representation of this pathname
- Pass this validated pathname on to further code, either as a String or some other object